# Crypto-Challenge - part 1

Tags: cipher

My university is having some sort of a challenge. I am really excited by this, but I can't even get through the first part of it.

I thought you guys might find it interesting:

Here it goes:

The first part involves decoding the following chipertext:

> FGPGZ AGCAE CRRVF GPWJG QCLFA QLFGV GQLUM HRJGU OWCUR CLFGE JCGOY EAGQU RQJGT GJQLG

Hint:

> Turn two to the left, then two to the right,
> Repeat, to get on the other side.
> Don't be afraid: go, see and conquer,
> You'll find secrets, fun and wonder!

I tried applying a Caesar shift, but it doesn't seem to be the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The key is to

> Shift two in one direction, then two in the other, back and forth

You get

> HEREB YIACC EPTTH ERULE SANDC ONDIT IONSO FTHIS QUEST ANDIC LAIMA CCESS TOLEV ELONE

Which is

> "Hereby I accept the rules and conditions of this quest and I claim access to level one"
>  when you move the spaces

Comment: Never thought of ignoring the form that it came into and to treat this one character at the time. Nicely done!